# Sending variable to another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm really stuck on what to do. My problem is that a PHP variable (or javascript/jQuery) is not being sent to another php file through an AJAX request that I have created. Ok, I am creating a chat application. It has a message textbox and a send button. When the send button is clicked, the ajax request works and it executes the php file I want it to (and I know this because it writes a ":" to my text file, which is correct), except that I get: "undefined index: message", because the message variable is not being sent to the php file! I have found numerous questions on this topic, but none of them seemed to help me, so I was hoping you guys would be able to figure it out.

Here is my test.php file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#chat").load("chat.txt");
        });
</script>

<script>    
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#send").click(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    url: 'chat.php',
                    data: '' + message,
                    success: function(response){
                        $("#chat").html(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
</head>

<body>

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }

?>

<style type="text/css">
    #chat {
        width: 194px;
        background-color: #292929;
        color: #493C9E;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
</style>

<pre id="chat">

</pre>

<form method="post">
    Message: <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send" name="send" onclick="return false;">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried everything I can think of and nothing is working! I have tried creating a message variable using JavaScript and jQuery, I have tried to insert php tags and create a php variable next to data. I've tried with and without an empty string. Some other code I tried was `data: { message: '123' }`. Also when I created a jQuery/JavaScript variable I alerted the value of the message, and it was exactly what I had typed into the message textbox.

chat.php:

```
<?php
            $file = "chat.txt";
            $handle = fopen($file, "a+");
            fwrite($handle, ": " . $message . "\n");
            echo "\n: " . $message;

?>
```

I have tried including the test.php file in the chat.php file, but to no avail. I also created the message variable `$message = $_POST['message'];` and the message data was meant to be sent from the test.php file. I've tried checking if the message variable was set (using `isset()`). In the test.php file I also tried creating the message variable through AJAX, `{ message: $message },`. And NOTHING seems to be working AT ALL!!!! This is really getting to me, so if someone could please help me, I'd really appreciate it. 
Thanx ALOT in advance :)
PS: If you need any other information, please just comment below, and I'll give it to you. And thanks to everyone for responding so fast in my previous questions :)

Comment: Please provide code on fiddle

Comment: What does this mean?  *"I also created the message variable $message = $_POST['message']; and the message data was meant to be sent from the test.php file"*

Comment: I meant, I created a message variable and it is meant to hold the value of the message in the textbox when the button is clicked, and send it to the chat.php file so that it can be used to write to the text file. I should have made that a bit clearer :)

Comment: `message` is never defined anywhere in your JS code.

Comment: Isn't this `data: '' + message,` related to it, or is the OP missing something other than that? @MarcB

Comment: @Fred-ii-: yes. `message` is a JS var and it's never defined anywher,e so the code's going to die with an undefined variable. and even if it was defined, the `data` parameter isn't being defined properly so it'll never show up in php. it should be something like `data: {name_of_post_var_in_php:'value to assign'}`.

Answer (score 1):

Few issues I identified:

1. Move your `isset()` to chat.php, not inside test.php.  If you have `$.ajax()`, then why need to have `isset()` but use it in your chat.php as part of grabbing and processing `$_POST[]`.
2. You are missing `var` and your ajax doesn't know which string to send.
3. Wrap up all of your jquery snippets into one tag instead of having 2 `$(document).ready(function()`
4. I always put my jQuery in the bottom of html ( right before `</body>` instead of inside `<head>`.

So as per my feedback, the following below would be what it should appear as per my coding approach:

test.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    #chat {
        width: 194px;   
        background-color: #292929;
        color: #493C9E;
        overflow: scroll;
    }
</style>

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<pre id="chat">
</pre>

<form id="chatForm" method="post">
    Message: <input type="text" id="message" name="message"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" id="send" name="send" onclick="return false;">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* notice I moved the jQuery script to bottom right before </html> instead of inside    <head> */
/* combine both of 2 jQuery into same grouping */

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chat").load("chat.txt");

/* use form id for ajax to manipulate the data so, I added id="chatForm" in your html form for this one: */

        $("#chatForm").submit(function(){ /* <-- use `submit()` so it'd handle the whole form at once */
var message = $( this ).serialize();  /* <-- this inkove ajax to know to expect string before sending to php */
                $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'chat.php',
                data: ''+ message,
                success: function(response){
                    $("#chat").html(response);
                } // end of success
            }); // end of $.ajax()
        }); // end of submit
    });// end of document ready
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in your chat.php

```
<?php

/* transfer isset() from test.php to this file and use it to wrap your fwrite function */

    if (isset($_POST['message'])) { 
        $message = $_POST['message'];
       $file = "chat.txt";
            $handle = fopen($file, "a+");
            fwrite($handle, ": " . $message . "\n");
            echo "\n: " . $message;
    }        
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an error function to you ajax call and see what is returned.

```
error: function(msg){alert(msg.status + " " + msg.statusText);}
```

Comment: Forgot to add this! I tried this and I got nothing, no alert box appeared, telling me what was wrong as it should have.

Comment: try adding an alert to the success function with the response, if the method is getting called you will either get a success or error.

Comment: I just did excactly that and this is what I got A long message. Here is the link: https://www.mediafire.com/?1lbv1ddv1p5cxas I tried response.status, and I go undefined!

Comment: are you using a browser debugger to check for errors and see what values are in your variables? i.e. in chrome press F12. It might help. Also it looks like the alert gave a hint as to what the issue is, your message variable is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You must take the variable with `$_POST` in `chat.php`
Like this:

```
<?php
            $file = "chat.txt";
            $handle = fopen($file, "a+");
            fwrite($handle, ": " . $_POST['message'] . "\n");
            echo "\n: " . $_POST['message'];

?>
```